# Remove duplicates from one column keeping whole rows

Tags: mysql

```
id | userid | total_points_spent
1  | 1      | 10
2  | 2      | 15
3  | 2      | 50
4  | 3      | 5
5  | 1      | 15
```

With the above table, I would first like to remove duplicates of `userid` keeping the rows with the largest `total_points_spent`, like so:

```
id | userid | total_points_spent
3  | 2      | 50
4  | 3      | 5
5  | 1      | 15
```

And then I would like to sum the values of `total_points_spent`, which would be the easy part, resulting in `70`.

Comment: the numbers shown in the 2 tables seem to be the result of a mysql query. If this is indeed the case, could you show us the code of this mysql query? Otherwise, what have you tried?

Comment: It isn't. It was just an example. I have tried using the `DISTINCT` key word, but it doesn't show the whole row, only the value of `userid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure the "remove" you meant is to delete or to select. Here is the query for select only max totalpointspend record respectively.

```
SELECT tblA.* 
  FROM ( SELECT userid, MAX(totalpointspend) AS maxtotal
           FROM tblA
           GROUP BY userid ) AS dt
INNER JOIN tblA 
    ON tblA.userid = dt.userid
   AND tblA.totalpointspend = dt.maxtotal           
ORDER BY tblA.userid
```